# i get error on Windows 7 64bit after i installed my C# program

Tags: c#, windows-7, installation

i installed my C# program (that work with access database) on windows 7 64 bit

and i get this error:

```
The Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine
```

what can be the problem ?

thank's in advance

Comment: There is no 64-bit version of that provider, there'll never be one.

Answer (score 1):

Your software is running in 64 bit mode, and the ODBC driver is 32 bit only.

You should change the manifest to run with 32-bit version of .Net. You can do this from the Visual Studio Configuration options.

Comment: To be specific, under the Build tab, set Platform target to x86.